# Use direct classes in gRPC to avoid data-copy

Tags: java, c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net

We want to avoid the data copy in gRPC communication.

I have a following (not a real) example in proto file:

```
message Person
{
    string id = 1;
    string Name = 2;
    string Address = 3;
}

message PersonId
{
    required string id = 1;
}

service PersonService
{
    rpc GetPersonById( PersonId ) returns Person;
}
```

And it works fine. But When I implement it, then I have copy my all data to the request:

```
class PersonServiceImpl : PersonService.MaterialServiceBase
{
    public override Task<Person> GetPersonById( PersonId request, ServerCallContext context )
    {
        Datamodel.Person person = GetPersonForDatabaseAsync(request.Id).Result;

        Task.FromResult( new Person() {
            Id = person.Id,
            Name = person.Name,
            Address = person.Address
            } );
    }
}
```

But it wold be very great, when we an avoid the data copy, because it is slow, and dangerous, when we add a new member to Person. The perfect code will be following:

```
    public override Task<Person> GetPersonById( PersonId request, ServerCallContext context )
    {
        return GetPersonForDatabaseAsync(request.Id);
    }
```

Is it possible?

We check the performance and the 25% of time is in marshaling and demarshaling, especially on large type, which has nested types for example Huge Orders.

I Add the java Tag, because it is relevant question in Java environment too.

Edit because of comment:

```
namespace Datamodel
{
    class Person
    {
        string Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So the question is, from other point of view: How should I change the `Datamodel.Person` to make it compatible with `gRPC` response.

Comment: It seems there is no solution for it, because lot of stuff is hard-coded in code generator.  If I derived from IMessage<T> my own, the I will lost lot of functionality,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible, because of the protobuf code generation. All member and function is hard-coded.

It would be great, when the gRPC gives a possibility to use an interface instead direct member definition is message class. This interface will be contains all the members and a create function.

So the generated code is changed from this:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
public void MergeFrom( pb::CodedInputStream input )
{
    uint tag;
    while ( ( tag = input.ReadTag() ) != 0 )
    {
        switch ( tag )
        {
            default:
                _unknownFields = pb::UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom( _unknownFields, input );
                break;
            case 10:
                {
                    Id = input.ReadString();
                    break;
                }
            case 18:
                {
                    Name = input.ReadString();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

To this:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
public void MergeFrom( pb::CodedInputStream input )
{
    uint tag;
    while ( ( tag = input.ReadTag() ) != 0 )
    {
        switch ( tag )
        {
            default:
                Instance.UnknownFields = pb::UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom( Instance.UnknownFields, input );
                break;
            case 10:
                {
                    Instance.Id = input.ReadString();
                    break;
                }
            case 18:
                {
                    Instance.Name = input.ReadString();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

where the `Instance` is an implementaion of the interface which is generated from protofile:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    private pb::UnknownFieldSet UnknownFields;
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If My `Datamodel.Person` implements the interface, and the generated `Person` message stores and retrieves the data across this `IPerson` interface, then we can avoid the datacopy, and thethe usage of the gRPC will be faster with more 25%.

I think this is a huge advantegae for gRPC Maybe [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) can do it. I can made c,c++, and c# changes, when we have clear concepts.

By the way, this will be a huge fore step for gRPC, because this is one of the reason why peoples uses the REST instead of it. In the REST world, there is possibility to retrieve the data directly to `Datamodel` structures with JSON `Serialize`. With `Deserialize` they can send directly the structure.

It must be a new option in protobuf file, and it is possible in all language witch supports interfaces.